# Apple Pay with Stripe - verification on Wordpress installation - GCP

Tags: wordpress, ssh, google-cloud-platform, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm trying to setup a new payment method - Apple Pay - that requires a domain verification with a txt file at that specific path:
https://example.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association

The file is there, when I log via FTP the path is correct, but when I try to open by URL I get a 404 error..

The folder .well-known is set to 755 permission
The txt file is set to 644
(the folder is placed right inside htdocs)

I'm using Google Cloud Platform, with a bitnami one-click wordpress installation

Comment: If you are getting a 404 the file is not there from the web server's view. What is the base directory for your Bitnami installation? Look at `bitnami.conf` and find the `VirtualHost` for your exact domain name. Then look at the `DocumentRoot`. The directory `.well-known` should be located there. On my system `bitnami.conf` is located at `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` and the DocumentRoot is `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`. Make sure the directory and file are owned by the correct user/group names (bitnami and daemon).

Comment: Review your web server log files for error messages: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`

Comment: As a last resort review your WordPress plugins. Look for anything that does error handling or redirects. Also, consider disabling all plugins while debugging.

Comment: My Document root is "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs" that means I'll have to place the folder here, right? Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, starting the the folder `.well-known`.

Comment: I executed the command sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/.well-known /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/.well-known and I checked the folder moved correctly.. but I still get a 404 on the file link

Answer (score 1):

If you have letsencrypt installed on your machine the directory you want is:
`/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/.well-known`